# Best Way to Create Application to Create JPEG Images (thumbnails) From PDFs

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf

I want to create a simple program that will convert a pdf to a jpg with the longest height or width set to a specific pixel amount and a 1px border applied. All computer that would use it would have Acrobat 5.0 or later installed. I'm not sure if I could pull this off with something like JavaScript in Acrobat itself or preferably a drag and drop functionality in a windows application written in C# or if there's some better way.

Comment: For the pdf-to-jpeg conversion part of the question, a similar question was asked here, and the accepted answer referred to a library that can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711942/convert-pdf-file-to-jpg-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned C# in your question tags, you can use [a .NET wrapper of ImageMagic](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) for using [Image Magic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which can be used to convert pdf to images.